Diode-less op amp circuits that can simulate a diode
Gyrators can be used to simulate circuit properties of inductors. Is there something similar you can do, where you use a circuit with no diode to simulate a diode?

What role should this diode play - switch, voltage stabilizer, or log/antilog converter?

Which diode properties do you want to simulate - rectification, the V-I curve, etc - ?

A GIC (generalized impedance converter) can make a capacitance look like its dual (inductance) but that's a very special situation. There's no real dual of a diode (though there are dual diodes). The exponential vs. log behavior of log and antilog amplifiers might be worth looking at. But this question is a bit too broad, I suggest narrowing the focus.

I think “emulate” is the correct term to use here.

You can use a MOSFET as a diode or a BJT transistor as a diode, however if you do this you won't get the same I-V curve as a diode. If you do this you must use caution.
As far as op-amps go you can use FETs or BJTs to replace a diode, they won't get the same results in feedback as a diode. FETs don't have the voltage drop of a diode, BJTs can have a similar drop when used in a diode configuration.

A FET with gate shorted to source has a very diode-like response, because you're then just looking at the body diode.

Gyrators are used to "simulate" inductors because even though they are more complex circuits, they can be physically MUCH smaller than the large inductors they are "simulating" (actually imitating).
Simulating or imitating a single plain diode would be pointless most of the time because diodes are the simplest elementary semiconductors with a simple function which would be pointless to replace with a WHOLE equivalent circuit comprised of multiple elements just to make them behave the same way AND there is no reduction in the size or space requirements.
The only time I can think of replacing a diode with a whole circuit is either to make it behave like an IDEAL diode (near-zero forward voltage drop) or to in some special case scenarios where it is really necessary for whatever reasons, including safety.

You can easily build something that appears to have impedance \$sL\$ (a gyrator having apparent inductance) using non inductive components and op-amps, in the same way you can produce something that appears to have impedance \$\frac{1}{sC}\$ (capacitance) using non-capacitive elements. This is because resistors, capacitors and inductors are all linear elements, and op-amps with negative feedback have linear response. You can combine linear elements in any way you like, to obtain whatever other linear response you desire.
Diodes are non-linear, and you can't produce non-linear behaviour from any combination of linear elements. In fact, diodes are something we employ to endow an otherwise linear system of resistors, capacitors, inductors and/or op-amps with some non-linear property, not the other way around.
No linear system can behave in a non-linear manner, unless it is pushed to some extreme where it is no longer behaving linearly. For instance, you could make an op-amp do something like voltage clamping, by providing it with power supplies that constrain its output voltage:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
On the left the diode prevents the potential at OUT1 from rising above 0.6V or so, so fed with a 5V amplitude sinusoid at IN, OUT1 looks like this:

This occurs because the diode's behaviour changes abruptly when the voltage across it exceeds 0.6V.
On the right, the op-amp is configured as a voltage follower, but its positive supply is only +0.6V, and the op-amp can't output greater than that. OUT2 is therefore also capped to a maximum of 0.6V:

The two circuits behave very similarly, but the second one is more expensive, might not work if you don't use the correct op-amp (my use of the AD8551 was very deliberate here), and is plain stupid in many respects.
You can't build non-linear systems using linear elements, unless you push those elements into some non-linear region of operation, such as saturation of an op-amp output, or saturation of a inductor's core. The diode is a non-linear element.

A diode has many properties, such as ... :

operating as a "current one way valve"
functioning as a crude "0.7V voltage ref" (but with a rather logarithmic IV characteristic around the knee)
under large reverse voltage, it becomes a zener (but you probably want a zener for that ...)

which properties do you want to simulate and why?

If your intent is to model the behavior of an actual diode using an op-amp, then it seems like you will need a diode somewhere to do that. Diodes have an exponential voltage-vs. current behavior that's modeled by the Shockley equation, as follows:

From this answer: Voltage across diode, Shockley equation
Now if your goal is to model the diode's forward/reverse behavior as if it were an ideal diode (that is, with no forward drop), that's certainly possible. You use a FET as a pass element, and sense the voltage across the FET with a comparator. There are specialized 'ideal diode' controllers that do this, but they all work on the same principle: they detect reverse bias voltage and turn off the FET in response.
Here's how you'd do it with an op-amp (simulate it here):

The 5V AC is half-wave rectified with practically no diode drop.
